# OSx pip command not found

Tags: python, macos, path, terminal, pip

I'm a very active user of Pythons `pip` command, which comes as a pre-installed python package with almost every version of OSx. I am running Yosemite and just installed the terminal IRC client '[WeeChat](https://weechat.org/)', which works well with no issues.

However, after installed WeeChat, I noticed my `pip` command doesn't work anymore. When I attempt to re-install it using another pre-installed python package `easy_install` I get the following messages:

```
pip 7.1.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
error: /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

When I browse to the `/usr/local/bin` directory I do in fact see 2 different pip directories, one that just says `pip` and the other that says `pip-2.7` which I'm assuming is for Python 2.7.

My `PATH` variables are as follows:

```
PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Has anyone experienced this or have any idea what the issue could be? Everything was working great with it up until I installed WeeChat.

Comment: Anything in `/usr/local/bin` is *not* part of the OS. What exactly did you install there in the first place?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the help of someone off IRC, I was able to get everything working again by essentially re-installing Python using `brew install python`

Comment: Great! Just out of curiosity - what exactly happened when you tried to run pip? I might come up with a quicker fix for the future.

Comment: It would simply tell me `pip command not found` which is very odd because I've used pip hundreds of times on this machine, just a day before it broke.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error for many times and the line

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

saved my day!

Hope this works!